# pdf2image poppler_path parameter does seem to work

Tags: poppler

I am using **pdf2image** from a `conda env` after installing poppler on my **Win10** system.

I try to use the poppler_path parameter available in the *convert_from_path* method but it seems that it does not work.

Anyone with experience with pdf2image on Win10 called from a conda env?
Thanks
Jerome

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, on my Windows 10 and it worked for me:

1) Download the last build from http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/

2) Extract its contents to "C:/Program Files (x86)/Poopler/"

3) Install pdf2image package dependency with your preferred method (my version is 1.11.0)

4) Python script:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
file = "my_pdf.pdf"
pages = convert_from_path(file, 200, poppler_path='C:/Program Files (x86)/Poopler/poppler-0.68.0/bin')    
for i, page in enumerate(pages):
     <process the page...>
```

Hope it helps!